# import fuction from package to another package

Tags: path, package, python-3.6, python-import, call

can you please tell me how can I import a function from poly.py to query.py

this is the directories tree :

```
my_project
    |_dataset
    |_execute
       |__poly.py
    |_search
       |__query.py
    |_determine
    |_optimize
    |_transmit
```

NB : my python version is 3.6.2 > 3.3 so _*init*.py is unuseful

Answer (score 0):

You need put those files in 1 folder and do `import filename`  or `from filename import function`